# Deliver high current through vias

Tags: pcb, current, via, manufacturing

There is a demand for a delivery of 3 A through several layers using vias.

Presented below in the picture is my PCB manufacturer's abilities regarding vias.

A single via can withstand 1.4 A. Are there any strategies regarding how to deliver this current, maybe through several vias in parallel?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The displayed via current is not a maximum, but rather a recommendation to keep the temperature under control. A rise of 20° to 30° in temperature is usally fine, but it depends on your application.

If you have the space to integrate multiple vias in parallel, go for it.

I would suggest going with conservative values of 500mA per via for a 10° rise or using even bigger vias if your manufacture allows it.

Here is a [tool](https://www.protoexpress.com/tools/via-current-capacity-temperature-rise-calculator/) for calculating temperature depending on via parameters.

Comment: Hello, i have a pulse of 50u seconds and 35% duty cycle ,is there a way you could recommend me to know by how much the temperature will rise after 17.5 seconds?